# Ambiguity in "translated" as an adjective?

Tags: adjectives, ambiguity

Suppose I have a German document that has been translated to produce an English document.

It seems that there are two sensible ways to interpret the following request:

> "Give me the translated document."

I have empirically confirmed this ambiguity (small sample size), where some people argue that the requested document is the German one and others argue that it is the English one.

Question: Is the phrase grammatically ambiguous or is there a correct way to interpret "translated" (a participle acting as an adjective) here?

Comment: Needless to say, this specific example can be disambiguated by using different words, i.e., "the original document" or otherwise.

Comment: Put me down as someone who considers the request ambiguous.  How large was that group in your survey?

Comment: Put me down with the other two who think it means the *Translation* of the German document, meaning the English one.

Comment: I think it's ambiguous. If you wanted to eliminate the ambiguity, you could distinguish the two by using the terms _original document_ (German version) and _translation_ (English version).